# Создание маски изображения с помощью cv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcgis

Пытаюсь создать маску изображения как показано в примере https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/geo-referencing-and-digitization-of-scanned-maps/

```
smd.create_mask(color_list=[[115, 178, 115]], color_delta=10, kernel_size=[2, 2], kernel_type="rect", show_result=True)
```

выдаёт ошибку

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [26], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 smd.create_mask(color_list=[[115, 178, 115]], color_delta=10, kernel_size=[2, 2], kernel_type="rect", show_result=True)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\_scannedmapdigitizer.py:1763, in ScannedMapDigitizer.create_mask(cls, color_list, color_delta, kernel_size, kernel_type, show_result)
   1760     os.mkdir(image_folder)
   1762 image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(input_folder, image_path))
-> 1763 rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   1764 hf = h5py.File(
   1765     os.path.join(
   1766         output_folder, image_name, "mask", "mask_color_details.h5"
   1767     ),
   1768     "w",
   1769 )
   1770 img_masks = [rgb_img]

error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function cv::cvtColor
```

При проверке размера и содержимого выдаёт

`image.size 16453125`

```
print (image)
[[[212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]
  ...
  [212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]]

 [[212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]
  ...
  [212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]]

 [[212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]
  ...
  [212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]
  [212 243 206]]

 ...

 [[  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]
  ...
  [  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]]

 [[  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]
  ...
  [  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]]

 [[  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]
  ...
  [  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]
  [  0   0 254]]]
```

Помогите разобраться в чем дело. По тому что удалось найти ошибка указывает на то что неправильно указан путь к изображению по другим что не срабатывает `rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` ввиду того что не rgb расцветка

Comment: Так проверьте, что в `image`, может он пустой. Возможно, `cv2` не смог нормально прочитать файл такого типа, или файл битый.

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Не, ну вы размер посмотрите, и немного хоть содержимое. `.size` кажется, ну и что-то типа `image[:10]` напечатайте

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Ну что-то не знаю прямо. А это вывод именно на проблемном файле? Попробуйте вывести эту инфу на нормально читаемом файле и на проблемном и сравните, может будет какая-то заметная разница.